# CSS image background and gradient - separate them into two lines?

Tags: css, background-image, linear-gradients

How can I separate

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), url("../images/3.jpg");
```

For example (does not work of course):

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,0,0,0));
background-image: url("../images/3.jpg");
```

Any ideas?

Comment: No, that is what the comma syntax is for. What are you trying to achieve? My guess is that you want the jpg on top; in that case, just change the order around.

Comment: @MrLister I want to add the image via inline html but keep the gradient in css file.

Comment: Okay then use inline html ? <div style="background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), url('../images/3.jpg');"></div>

Comment: @Highdef i think that is the only. thought it could be other ways.

Comment: You can use two nested elements; put one background into the parent and the other in the child.

Comment: We're not really sure what you're trying to achieve and in what way exactly.

Comment: Image via inline css and gradient in css file, seems clear to me what the OP is trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

You will need to separate the the gradient and the image with a comma.

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,0,0,0)),
            url("../images/3.jpg");
```